# How long does it take to heal shin splint?

Tags: running, long-distance-running, shins

I was doing regular jog for about 6-7 KM for two weeks. One day decided to do interval training and started running fast. After about 400m my left lower leg started to hurt. I continued slow run for another half a KM. Since then I cannot run as my left lower leg starts paining within 100 m. I believe it is shin splint. I have been resting since then. Wearing a crepe bandage to support my lower leg. It has been 15 days. How long does it take to heal. By lower leg I mean, front part of the calf.

Comment: Did you go see a doctor?

Comment: Go see a doctor. A shin sprint usually takes a bit longer to develop than 5-6 runs, so it might be something else. Also most often - in my experience at least - you don't "feel" the hurt from the shin sprint during the run, but only after the run and at the very start of the run...

Comment: When I first started running, I would get the same symptoms.  I was in good cardio shape, but my legs weren't used to the impact.  I was also using poor running form.  I tried a few times to start running again after thinking I had healed, but the symptoms returned.  Here's what you should do: study proper running form so as to reduce the amount of impact on your bones, allow yourself time to heal (maybe 2-3 weeks before you try ANY running), then start very, very gradually to get up to your 6-7km runs.  Maybe run 1-2km twice the first week, 2-3km twice the second week, etc.

Comment: Also, ensure you are wearing the correct trainers for your gait. For example, if you over-pronate and wear a shoe with insufficient support then as your foot rolls when you strike the ground it will put excessive strain on your lower leg muscles which can result in shin discomfort.

Answer (score -1):

Like others have suggested, you need to see a medical person,  I would suggest a physio or osteopath.

I think it is unlikely to be shin splints, and more likely to be chronic compartment syndrome. http://orthoinfo.aaos.org/topic.cfm?topic=a00204
This is when you increase exercise volume and the muscles grows faster than the muscle facia.  It can be extremely painful.  But the good news is you can recover much quicker than from shin splints.  A series of very deep massage, will help a lot.  An Osteopath really helped with mine.   This is not to be confused with acute compartment syndrome which is a medical emergency.  See the above link for a better explanation.  I have a lot of running/run coaching experience, but I'm not medically trained, so please do get some expert advice.